# Placing class constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

Why this code is incorrect?

```
class Method
{
public:
   Method(decltype(info2) info1);
   virtual ~Method(){}
protected:
  QSharedPointer<info> info2;
};
```

But this code is correct:

```
class Method
{
public:
   virtual ~Method(){}
protected:
  QSharedPointer<info> info2;
public:
  Method(decltype(info2) info1);   
};
```

why place of class constructor is important?
I thought that place of definition class constructor isnt important.

Comment: Maybe the compiler isn't able to determine the type of `info2` before you declared it

Comment: @DragonRock The compiler does what the standard mandates, could you provide a reference?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.unqual#7

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Or it doesn't. Or standard doesn't cover it, an unlikely oversight, but I can't find statement which would require definition before usage. Although there is a passage saying the `decltype` operand type does not have to be complete. The question here is a meaningful reference, or it's lack.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki If I had a reference, I would've answered instead of leaving a comment starting with "maybe".

Answer (score 1):

I believe this part of the standard is relevant **[basic.scope.class]/1.1**:

> The potential scope of a name declared in a class consists not only of the declarative region following the
>   name’s point of declaration, but also of all function bodies, default arguments,
>   exception-specification
>   s,
>   and
>   brace-or-equal-initializers
>   of non-static data members in that class (including such things in nested
>   classes).

Note that it only mentions **default** arguments. So this works since the decltype is referred in a default argument:

```
Method(QSharedPointer<int> info1 = decltype(info2)())
```

And this also works since it's inside a body:

```
Method(<...>)
{
    decltype(info2) info3;
}
```

However your example does not work because such a placement of a decltype is not covered by the paragraph I quoted, thus the name `info2` is considered out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

Place of QSharedPointer info2;

is important. 
'info2' should be defined before using it into decltype (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype).

Next would not work either:

```
void f() {
    d();
}

void d() {
}
```

Comment: But that example works in class definition. Why `decltype` does not work though?